# Autofilter, then xlcelltypevisible selects empty rows

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I'm new to VBA and programming in general. I'm working with large tables of data in excel - my worksheets routinely have 65K rows.

I want to take two columns as my input and have excel write formula output to two new columns. I don't need to do this for all the rows, so I tried to filter my data and apply the calculation output only to the remaining visible cells. However, my code appears to add a bunch of extra blank rows to the bottom (row count balloons to 145K!) and then tries to calculate those as well, which makes the macro hang.

How can I fix this range selection problem? Also, are there better ways to do the sorting? Thank you!

```
Sub CalcSpec()
Dim s As Worksheet
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If (Left(s.Name, 7) = "Channel" And Right(s.Name, 1) = "1") Then
        s.Activate
        UserMassInput.Show 1 'Sets up value in R2C21 referenced later
        'Select only relevant data from cycles 1-5
        With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter
        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<=5"
        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("2", "3", "5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
        'Here's where I try and fail to select only the relevant range
        Dim cyCells As Range
        Set cyCells = Columns("R:S").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'Apply formula to calculate specific capacities
        For Each cell In cyCells
            cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*1000/R2C21"
        Next cell
        'Label all the new columns
        ActiveSheet.Range("R1").Value = "Spec CC"
        ActiveSheet.Range("S1").Value = "Spec DC"
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Next s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like your code is adding anything to the sheet, perhaps the empty rows are already there and you're only noticing them because of the operation?  Because you're doing:

`.Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter`

Excel is interpreting the range as that size.  There are a number of ways to find the "last used row" in a worksheet or range.  Try this method:

http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/

Once you identify the last used row, change your autofilter range to explicitly define the range being filtered.

Try something like this.  It is pretty much fully tested on my end using some dummy data on a (much) smaller worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalcSpec()
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim filteredRange As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim a As Range
'## First, disable automatic calculation and screenupdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = -4135 'xlCalculationManual

For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    '## I modified this logic to use a GoTo instead of putting everything inside an If Block
    If Not ((Left(s.Name, 7) = "Channel" And Right(s.Name, 1) = "1")) Then GoTo NextSheet

    UserMassInput.Show 1 'Sets up value in R2C21 referenced later
    'Select only relevant data from cycles 1-5
    With s
    '## Define our range using the LAST_ROW of the worksheet
        Set filteredRange = .Range("A1:Q" & LastRow(s))
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    '## Apply autofilter Explicitly to the range defined above
        filteredRange.AutoFilter Field:=6, _
                                 Criteria1:="<=5"
        filteredRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, _
                                 Criteria1:=Array("2", "3", "5"), _
                                 Operator:=xlFilterValues

        'Here's where I try and fail to select only the relevant range
        Dim cyCells As Range
        Set cyCells = filteredRange.Resize(, 2).Offset(0, 17).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'Apply formula to calculate specific capacities
    '## I'm pretty sure you need to iterate the AREAS in a filtered range,
    '   and then the cells/rows within each AREA
        For Each a In cyCells.Areas
            For Each cl In a.Cells
                cl.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]*1000/R2C21"
            Next
        Next

        'Label all the new columns
        .Range("R1").Value = "Spec CC"
        .Range("S1").Value = "Spec DC"
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
NextSheet:
Next s


'## Remember to turn screenupdating and calculation back ON
Application.Calculation = -4105 'xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function LastRow(Optional ws As Worksheet = Nothing) As Long
If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim r As Long
r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow = r
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding multiple conditions... I do try to avoid using `GoTo` statements -- they get confusing to follow and make it harder to maintain your code over time.  I used it in this case only because it truly appeared you just wanted to ignore sheets where those condition(s) were not met.

For multiple conditions and different operations for each, nested `If` statements and/or using `Select Case` statements is usually the way I prefer to go.  You could do something like this instead:

```
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Left(s.Name,7) = "Channel" Then
        Select Case Right(s.Name, 1) 
            Case "%" 
            ' 
            '
            ' Within this block you put your code
            ' to do opertations on sheets like Channel*%
            ' or, call an appropriate subroutine
            '
            Case "1"
            '
            ' Within this block you put your code
            ' do operations on sheets like Channel*1
            ' or, call an appropriate subroutine
            '
            '
            ' NOTE: You can add as many Case statements _
            '       as you need, BEFORE the "Case Else"
            Case Else
            ' do operations on other sheets, or ignore them

            '
            '
            '
        End Select
    End If
    If Left(s.Name, 10) = "Statistics" Then
        Select Case Right(s.Name, 1) 
            Case "%" 

            Case "1"

            Case Else

        End Select
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You were right that I wasn't noticing all the empty rows, because Excel does that thing where it won't scroll down further unless you mash on the down arrow. Thank you for your clear answer.

A question about style: I wrote this with If/Then loops because I deal with multiple cases. In particular, if a sheet is named "Channel_%" I do one calculation; if a sheet is named "Statistics_%" I do another calculation. Is it possible AND better to do it with IfNot/Then in this situation?

Comment: It's possible but would not be my preference. I think you would be better off (and the code would be more easy to read) if you used several `If/Then` blocks, and/or a `Select Case` statement.  I added an example for you.